# Selenium IE driver can not find newly opened window

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I'm using IEdriver (32-Bit),IE (version 11 installed) and Selenium 3.3.1,
and below is code which I've used to switch to new window.

```
        String parentWin = driver.getWindowHandle();

        click(By.cssSelector("#linkID_OpenNewWin"));

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        Set<String> winList = driver.getWindowHandles();

        for (String winHandle : winList)
        {   
            if (!winHandle.equals(parentWin))
            {
                driver.switchTo().window(winHandle); // switch focus of WebDriver to the next found window handle 
            }
        }
```

When i try to execute above code using IE driver then it's unable to find newly opened window,
But with Chrome driver it execute as expected and all windows get handled.

Answer (score 1):

I can see a few problems with this code.

Firstly, you should probably set your implicit wait before you click the link, otherwise it could, in theory at least, continue before the new window is opened completely.  Secondly, while it's likely that there are only two windows in a test case, the parent plus the new, the loop should work fine, but if for some reason there were additional windows (tabs) there is no break; statement, so your loop would continue.  It's most likely the position of your implicit wait, but it's a good programming practice to exit loops when you find a match.

Comment: Thanks, actually I've added only sample code from test, i would use return statement in my actual code.And there are only two windows.
When i use driver other then IE, i can see two window found in set.While with IE driver i can find only one parent window in set.

Comment: So i suppose the problem here is with some IE compatibility setting and not with code.

Comment: You could try this after the switch: driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); (use it in both directions - there and back)

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't use implicit waits... prefer explicit waits, e.g. `WebDriverWait`. It will help you control the flow of your script in a more deterministic way.

My guess is that your script is moving on before the window actually appears for IE. I would suggest that you get a count of the number of window handles, then click the link that spawns the new window, and then wait for the window handle count to increase by 1. Now you know the window is opened and you can proceed to grab the new window handle and switch to it.

```
int expectedNumberOfWindows = driver.getWindowHandles().size() + 1; // or you can hardcode 2 if it should always be 2
String parentWin = driver.getWindowHandle();
click(By.cssSelector("#linkID_OpenNewWin"));
new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(expectedNumberOfWindows));
switchToNewWindow(parentWin);
// do stuff in new window
```

I typically put code that I plan to reuse into functions. Here's one that switches to the new window, i.e. the one that isn't the parent window.

```
public void switchToNewWindow(String currentWindow)
{
    for (String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
        if (!winHandle.equals(currentWindow))
        {
            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This really only works deterministically in the case where you have a single existing window and you spawn a single new window. In other cases, it will just switch to the first window that isn't the parent window which may or may not be the window you want.